# Prestashop Error 404 at moving to server

Tags: prestashop

At moving from local to a server my prestashop web, appears all the text (I think it connects correctly to the database), but it doesn´t visualizing any images,CSS,etc... I´ve modified config/settings.inc.php file
and modified PS_SHOP_DOMAIN, PS_SHOP_DOMAIN_SSL and SHOP_URL from the database and also deleted the .htaccess file.
Thanks!
[image: capture how it looks]

The same is with the backoffice:
[image: capture backoffice]

Answer (score 1):

you can do it by two ways:

1. navigate into backoffice to SEO&URL link, set correct values for `Shop domain` & `SSL domain` & `Base URI` fields. Save & update page.

or

2. in DB find tables:

**ps_configuration**, set correct values for `PS_SHOP_DOMAIN` and `PS_SHOP_DOMAIN_SSL`

**ps_shop_url** set correct values for `domain`, `domain_ssl`, `physical_uri`

Answer (score 0):

Some Prestashop installs, sometimes have SSL ON (don't know why).

If you are installing it on a server with no SSL certificate, all images and styles will not be loaded and the PHP scripts display barebones HTML pages.

To solve this:

1. In your Prestashop directory, delete all install directories and files to get the platform running.
2. Type your admin URL, example: *http://yourstore.me/psadmin*, log in with a registered valid admin user, and go to to `PREFERENCES->CONFIGURATION` and turn all SSL parameters to `off`.

Comment: This might help the issue, but any advice that includes "turn SSL off", especially for a store / web-shop situation whould contain a warning I believe?