# Moving prestashop to another server : purge cache without /admin access

Tags: css, caching, prestashop

I just moved my 1.6 Prestashop site to another server.

2 problems :

1) old cahe url seems remain  site.com/themes/autumn/cache/v_8_d5430c134532c792c7791cb838d55ad_all.css

(I have already removed /cache/smarty/cache + compile + /theme/autumn/cache/ files)
=> there is no style on webpage.

=> How to to purge these theme cache ? I'm developper : can i purge table in database ?

2) on site.com/admin0205, I have Forbiden message "Forbidden Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe" (i cant access to admin)

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

1) I already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33928693/prestashop-error-404-at-moving-to-server/33934663#33934663), you need to change old domain name to new in 2 DB tables

2) looks like should be resolved together with 1)

Comment: Seems the problem is not about the domain name because, it didn't change.

Comment: do you have correct read/write/owner permissions on files and folders?